How to test calls of a mocked dataclass in Python?
I want to write a unit test to a function which instantiates a dataclass twice followed by calling its method. However, the actual calls of the instantiation includes the calling of the method. This is confusing to me.
person.py:
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str

    def work(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is working")


def run_person():
    # It instantiates Person twice.
    for n in ["John", "Jack"]:
        person = Person(name=n)  # Instantiate a person
        person.work()  # Calling its method .work()


test_person.py:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call, patch

from person import run_person


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("person.Person")  # Patch the Person dataclass
    def test_run_person(self, mock_person):

        mock_person.return_value = MagicMock()
        
        # This is my expectation. It should call Person() twice.
        # But the actual calls is 
        # [call(name='John'), call().work(), call(name='Jack'), call().work()]
        expected_calls = [call(name="John"), call(name="Jack")]

        run_person()

        mock_person.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


The test gives an error:
Expected: [call(name='John'), call(name='Jack')]
  Actual: [call(name='John'), call().work(), call(name='Jack'), call().work()]

Can you please explain why I receive the error message above. Shouldn't the call of Person() and the call of Person.work() be separated? How to write this test properly?

You're both instantiating a person and calling its work method in run_person, so both calls are getting picked up.

@AndrewYim, thanks for your comments. I think the calls of work() method should be separated from the instantiations of Person. So mock_person.assert_has_calls should only contain the 2 instantiations.

The reason you see the list of calls, including the calls to .work() is because the mock_calls includes calls to return_value mocks, which is checked by assert_has_calls.
Because @patch("person.Person") replaces the entire Person class with a MagicMock, any instantiation of Person will be an instance of the original return_value MagicMock. Please note that this will return the same instance of MagicMock for both instantiations of Person.
Now, how to write this test differently depends on what you want to test.
If instantiating Person has no side-effects, I would return the list of persons from run_person() and only mock Person.work to prevent it's sideffects.
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(eq=True)
class Person:
    name: str

    def work(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is working")


def run_person():
    # It instantiates Person twice.
    persons = []
    for n in ["John", "Jack"]:
        person = Person(name=n)  # Instantiate a person
        person.work()  # Calling its method .work()
        persons.append(person)
    return persons

import unittest
from unittest.mock import call, patch

from person import run_person, Person


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("person.Person.work")
    def test_run_person(self, mock_work):

        persons = run_person()
        assert persons == [Person(name="John"), Person(name="Jack")]
        # Optionally you can also check if .work() was called
        mock_work.assert_has_calls([call(), call()])
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


thanks for your answer. Your explanation is correct. You are right that with mock_person.return_value, the two Person instances actually use the same MagicMock() object. I have posted my own answer with the corrections. Your answer is useful for testing the calls of the work() method. However, it changes the original code which did not return a list[Person].

I figured it out. My code mock_person.return_value = MagicMock() in my question is a mistake.
The mock_person should not use returne_value since Person is instantiated twice. So it should use side_effect.
The only thing needs to change is this. And the correct version is
mock_person.side_effect = [MagicMock(), MagicMock()].
